# Equivalent of Python's comprehensive list operation on string in R

Tags: python, r, string, list-comprehension

I want to perform operations on a list of characters in **R** as describe below:

1. Keep only what is after the '-'
2. Then keep only the four first characters of the remaining (complete by 'J' if its length is lower than four)
3. Put everything in upper case

**Example in Python**

```
lt = ['LTA-Yokudo', 'LTA-Luo', 'LTA-Kawasaki']
[str(x).split('-')[1][:4].upper().ljust(4, 'J') for x in lt]
```

**Expected result**

```
['YOKU', 'LUOJ', 'KAWA'] # in Python
c('YOKU', 'LUOJ', 'KAWA') # in R
```

Note that string in the list will always contain the character '-'.

What would be the best solution to do so in R ?
Thank you

Comment: use reticulate and call your python code in r ;)

Comment: Can you assume that the part before the `-` is always 3 characters?

Comment: @joran: Yes we can assume the prefix will be always "LTA-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `stringr` (and the pipe operation from `magrittr`).

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

lt <- c('LTA-Yokudo', 'LTA-Luo', 'LTA-Kawasaki')

lt2 <- lt %>%
  str_extract(pattern = "(?<=-)[A-Za-z]*") %>% # Extract letters after -
  str_sub(start = 1, end = 4) %>% # Get four letters
  str_pad(width = 4, pad = "J", side = "right") %>% # Add J at the end
  str_to_upper() # To lower case
lt2
# [1] "YOKU" "LUOJ" "KAWA"
```

Comment: Assuming the prefix is always the same you could do it in the one-liner `str_sub(lt, 5, 8) %>% str_pad(4, "j", side = "right") %>% str_to_upper`.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A base R approach:

```
> x <- c('LTA-Yokudo', 'LTA-Luo', 'LTA-Kawasaki')
> x1 <- toupper(substr(x,5,8))
> ifelse(nchar(x1) == 3,paste0(x1,"J"),x1)
[1] "YOKU" "LUOJ" "KAWA"
```

Comment: @Parfait That's why I asked in a comment above whether we could assume the strings always began with "LTA-" and the OP seemed to imply that we could. But yes, without that assumption you'd have to do something different.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following non-looped solution in base R

```
lt = c('LTA-Yokudo', 'LTA-Luo', 'LTA-Kawasaki')

n <- toupper(substr(lt, regexpr('-', lt)+1, regexpr('-', lt)+4))
ifelse(nchar(n)==3, paste0(n, 'J'), n) 

# [1] "YOKU" "LUOJ" "KAWA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the stringr package (within tidyverse), you could do something like this.

```
library(tidyverse)

lt = c('LTA-Yokudo', 'LTA-Luo', 'LTA-Kawasaki')

##If you want lower case
new_1 <- str_to_lower(str_sub(str_replace(lt, "^.*-",""),start = 1, end = 4))

new_1 

##If you want upper case
new_2 <- str_to_upper(str_sub(str_replace(lt, "^.*-",""),start = 1, end = 4))
new_2
```